# Name of a theorem about the existence and uniqueness of a solution of a language equation

Tags: formal-languages

I'm looking for the name of this theorem:

> Let $P$, $Q$ be languages. Let $X$ be a language variable. Then the
>   language equation $X=PX + Q$ (here $+$ denotes union) has a solution
>   $X=P^*Q$, and the solution is unique if the null string doesn't belong
>   to $P$.

Answer (score 2):

Arden's Rule.

(That was my answer, but the rules of Stackexchange force me to continue to at least 30 characters)